# Can't write to blob storage from Azure Spark Cluster

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

I am working on a notebook in azure synapse using pyspark for creating a parquet file.

When running i am getting the following errorCaused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: This operation is not permitted on a non-empty directory.My directory is empty, I went to check the folder and some files are written in it, but after few minutes the error appears.

Thank you for your attention.

I use the following code

```
df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(path)
```

Comment: try to delete the directory then write again, for example `import shutil
   shutil.rmtree(path)    
df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(path)`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the same code `df.write.mode('overwrite').parquet(path)` and I have encountered the same error like you have received.
[image]

To resolve this I have tried the approach that reads data from a CSV file located in the **"dir1/CSV"** directory of the "**source**" container in **Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2**, converts it into a DataFrame, and then writes it back to the "**dir1/**" directory of the "**destination**" container in **Parquet format.**

The below is the code:

```
sourceaccountname ="synapsestorageaug02"
Sourcecontainer= "source"
SourceLinked Service = "AzureDataLakeStorage_ls"
Sourcefilelocation = " dir1/CSV"
Destinationaccountname="synapsestorageaug02"
destinationcontainer="destination"
destinationfile="dir1/"
spark.conf.set('spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName','AzureDataLakeStorage_ls')
spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type','com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedTokenProvider')
df= f'abfss://source@synapsestorageaug02.dfs.core.windows.net/'
print(df)
mssparkutils.fs.ls(df)
File= f'abfss://source@synapsestorageaug02.dfs.core.windows.net/dir1/CSV'
print(File)
source_df = spark.read.format('csv').option('header','true').option('inferschema','true').load(File)
source_df.show()
destpath = f'abfss://destination@synapsestorageaug02.dfs.core.windows.net/dir1/'
source_df.write.mode('overwrite').format('Parquet').option('header','true').save(destpath)
```

In the above code I have created a linked service for the ADLS GEN 2 and provided required access

Know more about the [Secure credentials with linked services using the mssparkutils](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-secure-credentials-with-tokenlibrary?pivots=programming-language-python)

*****Note**:** **Ensure the synapse system have the blob storage data contributor access for that storage account.
Blob storage data contributor access is required for user and service that you are trying to access(ASA).***

To set up the connection between the storage account and the Synapse using the linked service you can use the below code:

```
spark.conf.set('spark.storage.synapse.linkedServiceName','AzureDataLakeStorage_ls')
spark.conf.set('fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type','com.microsoft.azure.synapse.tokenlibrary.LinkedServiceBasedTokenProvider')
df= f'abfss://source@synapsestorageaug02.dfs.core.windows.net/'
print(df)
mssparkutils.fs.ls(df)
```

Above code display the directories in side the container we have to use
[image]

```
destpath = f'abfss://destination@synapsestorageaug02.dfs.core.windows.net/dir1/'  source_df.write.mode('overwrite').format('Parquet').option('header','true').save(destpath)
```

The above code writes the source_df DataFrame to the destination path in **Parquet** format. It uses the **write.mode('overwrite')** to overwrite any existing data, **format('Parquet')** to specify the output format as Parquet, and option('header','true') to include the header in the Parquet files. Finally, the data is saved to the destination path using **save(destpath)**.

**Output:**
[image]